# How to clean data to produce a smooth histogram

Tags: python, kernel-smoothing, histogram, smoothing

Is there any way to 'clean' a set of data to produce a smooth histogram, ie. without overrepresentative bins? Looking for solution in python3.

At the moment I have a histogram with overcounted bins:
[histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgSyf.png)

So far I've tried KDE but I don't know how to get Quantiles of it - how to divide it into k equal areas.

---

Thanks for your response.

Indeed, the goal is to cluster my one-dimensional dataset in such a way, to get the best visual separation when displaying it on a colour map. Mean - at which values should I border my bins.

I build a colour palette on historical data (shown on [histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgSyf.png)) and use this style to the current data. So far I used Quantiles, but I wondering, how it would affect my colouring if I get rid of these quantitative peaks (assuming the number of classes is stable).

For example, **1**s is divided into separate class only because it is very numerous.

Comment: Unlike forum-style discussion sites, Cross Validated threads do not consist of 
a sequence of posts forming a conversation between the original poster and the 
answerers. We use a Q&A style where the question is posted once at the top, and 
is updated (using the "edit" button) where necessary for clarification. Sometimes 
it makes sense to ask a new, follow-up question instead of editing the old one. 
Please don't use the "answer" space to post clarifications to your own questions 
- have a look at the [tour] to understand how our site works.

Comment: Showing the same value in different bins makes no sense. For a variable on $[0,1]$ why not just show bins with break points$0(0.1)1$?

Answer (score 1):

The histogram arises, I guess, because what you are showing is the result of dividing integers that are mostly or at least often small, so some values are much more common than others. I don't think it is helpful, or even good terminology, to talk about bins being "over-representative" or even "over-represented".

Kernel density estimation is challenging here because you have both exact zeros and exact ones, it seems, and it's an uphill challenge to respect those facts without artefacts.

I think you have four main options open to you.

0. Accept the histogram as what it is. Here you should know, as we don't, who will be looking at the graph and what they might find interesting or helpful or that they might want to know about. For example, I am guessing at a very large number of ratios each based on very little information. How the histogram arises is what I would want to know as a report reader and I wouldn't want you to mess with your data in pursuit of a simpler graph.
1. A histogram with larger bin width, say of the order of 0.05.
2. A square root scale for bin counts which will dampen the spikes.
3. A quantile plot or (empirical cumulative) distribution function plot showing cumulative probability on one axis and value on the other axis, which won't remove the spikes but will make them less disconcerting.

These are general ideas that should be easily manageable in any decent software.

Your last sentence seems to hint that you want to bin these data for some other purpose, which is a different question. On the face of it, implying that a smooth representation of the distribution makes sense rather contradicts the idea that binning into disjoint intervals also is a good thing to do.

Comment: If you found this answer helpful, then please consider 
[upvoting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) 
and/or 
[accepting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) 
it.